# How Can I Share the Car interface between classes and add Type Checking To CarItem class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've made a simple example that highlights a few of the problems / not-understandings I'm having with TypeScript. I created a simple list of cars that reference a caritem detail view.  Code is below and also on stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ocjswh

My Questions:

1. How do I get typechecking to work in CarItem.tsx? I've tried car: Car but that is not correct
2. What is the proper way to import react and react-dom? I tried import as with no success
3. I want to share my interface "Car" between index.tsx and CarItem.tsx so if I add another attribute, I don't have to add it to both places.  Once I have a large number of interfaces in my project, what is best way to do this?

Index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import CarItem from './CarItem';

interface Car
{
  id: number,
  model: string
}

interface Cars {
  cars: Car[];
}


const App : React.FunctionComponent<Cars>  = ({cars}) => {

  const myCars = [{
    id: 101, model: 'midget'
  },{
    id:102, model: 'spitfire'
  },{
    id: 103, model: 'tr6'
  }]

  return (
    <ul>
      {myCars.map(function(data){
          return (
          <CarItem car={data} />
          )
        }
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

CarItem.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Car
{
  id: number,
  model: string
}

export default ({car}) => {
  return (
    <li key={car.id}>...{car.model}</li>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this make index.tsx type safe with the cars parameter?  Then after that is done, how to share type type info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a lot of problem with this code. I refactored it and try to fix it all.
The answers to your questions:

1. I fixed the type for CarItem
2. There is nothing wrong with the import, they works. The editor has some syntax highlight problem.
3. You can export and import the interfaces as well.

Here is the corrected files

index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CarItem, {Car} from './CarItem';

const App : React.FunctionComponent  = () => {

  const myCars: Car[] = [{
    id: 101, model: 'midget'
  },{
    id:102, model: 'spitfire'
  },{
    id: 103, model: 'tr6'
  }]

  return (
    <ul>
      {myCars.map(function(data){
          return (
           <CarItem key={data.id} car={data} />
          )
        }
      )}
     </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

CarItem.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface Car
{
  id: number,
  model: string
}

interface Props {
  car: Car;
}

const CarItem: React.FunctionComponent<Props>  = ({car}) => {
  return (
    <li>...{car.model}</li>
  )
}

export default CarItem;
```

And the project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uknhel?file=index.tsx